# python/django buildout error while loading settings module

Tags: python, django, settings, buildout

I am trying to setup my project with buildout but i have problem. My **buildout.cfg**

```
[buildout]
parts = django
eggs = 
    psycopg2

[versions]
djangorecipe = 1.5

[django]
recipe = djangorecipe
project = myproject
settings = settings
wsgi = true
eggs = ${buildout:eggs}
```

when i try to run development server with **bin/django runserver** it says:

```
Error loading the settings module 'syslog.settings': No module named settings
```

Any idea how can i fix this problem?

Comment: is settings in the directory of `manage.py` ? your relative paths might be messed up

Comment: If there is a `syslog` module have a look at the directory.